# php database empty array

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

> does anyone understand why the code is returning empty array

```
$name = 'login';
$data = 'user2';
$sql = 'SELECT :name FROM test.users WHERE :name=:data';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute([':name' => $name, ':name' => $name, ':data' => $data]);
$res = $sth->fetchAll();
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: Also, if you're trying to select a value you already know (if this *could* return anything, it would just be the value contained in `$data`), you're probably looking for something like `Select Count()...`

Comment: BTW, if your previous questions __have correct answers__, that help you - __accept__ such answers.

Answer (score 5):

Two reasons:

- You cannot bind **field name**.
- You cannot use placeholder more than **once** (`:name`)